# Laravel 4 create table from construct

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, create-table

I'm trying to create a table in laravel 4 from a construct function, but it's not working.

I have search online for a proper way to do this which led me to raw. But raw expects a table name, or at least that is what I made of it.

So I looked a little further and found a DB::only function. But it throws this error:

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection' does not have a method 'only'
```

So there you have it, I would really like a solution for this seeing my project requires it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, found it:

```
DB::statement($sql);
```